# Physiology of benign eye twitching?

Tags: physiology

About four times in my life I have experienced the feeling of my eyelid fluttering for a few minutes by itself, and then it stops.

I have talked to other people who have had the same experience so I presume there is no pathology.

Could someone please explain the physiology behind these random eye twiching experiences that I and many others have had?

Comment: Could the down-voter please comment on how the question can be improved?